# How to generate serial number while select all data from table?

Tags: mysql

I want serial number at first position in SQL result.

I have found some similar solution, which is working:

```
select *,@a:=@a+1 serial_number from tableName,(SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;
```

but I'm expecting

```
select @a:=@a+1 serial_number,* from tableName,(SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;

serial_number|Name    |...
---------------------------------
  1          | Abc    |...
  2          | Def    |...    
  3          | Ghi    |... 
  4          | Jkl    |...
  5          | Mno    |...
```

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is... the order of the fields is displayed based on the order you put in the select

Comment: filed "Name" is just example, i puted dot after, which i mean, the more column will be show(all column).

Comment: your second query will return what you expect. What is the issue?

Comment: No, here can't use  "*" after serial number, try it.

Comment: that's obvious. You have to list explicitly the fields

Comment: i have more than 55 column, and those all dynamic generating so, i have to to * , do you know the solution...?

Comment: store the serial in the db already (eg. using autoincrement field) and put it as first field in the table structure. Then you can go with just a SELECT *. Serial number should be stored in the db to ensure it is unique and it doesn't change in case you alter the query. With your logic the same item can have a different SN just if you order differenty the record

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to generate the serial number by your SQL query since there is a built in feature of the database storage that will do the job for you.

Just make your `serial_number` datafield to be the `PRIMARY KEY` that will have default value`AUTO_INCREMENT`.

The database will manage unique values for you :)

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
serial_number INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
.
.
)
```

And then you will run simple query

```
SELECT serial_number, * FROM tableName;
```

See it live: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87c45/2

Comment: even if i do, than also your select query will not work, becoz * can't use after here. by the way
my question is to generate serial number on select query, if i have SN already than my Would not have rised. :)

Answer (score 0):

In table where are multiple columns and you need to change order of the columns in your result set just specify the names of the columns. To list all columns from the same table just use the `table name` followed by `dot` and `*`, ie `tableName.*`

```
SELECT serial_number, name, tableName.* FROM tableName;
```

Comment: ok, great! Please accept the solution for other users to know that it is the solution for this kind of problem.